# Chaining *= += operators

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
aaa = np.random.rand(20, 1)
aaa *= 200
aaa -= 100
```

I wonder if it is possible to chain `*=` and `-=` operators on the same line. So, the loop over the array would be done only one time and I suppose a slight gain in performance results (of course for big arrays).

Comment: Why would you assume `aaa *= 200` is faster than `aaa = aaa * 200` ?

Comment: `np.add(np.multiply(aaa,200,out=aaa),100,out=aaa)` might work.  Do your own timings.

Comment: @Tom Wojcik. Very good remark. I supposed that with `*=` there was only one operation because there was only one operator and with `a=a*200`, there were two operations multiplication and then affectation. It is not the case, second solution is faster. I am going to ask a new question when I will have done tests.

Comment: `np.add.at` describes an unbuffered in place `ufunc` operation.  This is useful for `a[indicies]+=b` cases where indices contains duplicates.  Due to buffering this does not produce the same thing as an iterative calculation.  Remember `numpy` is python; it does not rework python syntax or interpretation.  It just adds a new class with fast compiled methods.  I like to think of it as a LEGO set.  It has many fancy pieces, but it does not include a custom plastic injection machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot chain assignments in Python the way you can in C.

That is because in C an assignment is an *expression*: it has a value that can be assigned to a variable, or used in another expression. C got this idea from Algol, and those who come from the Pascal tradition tend to regard it as a misfeature. Because...

It is a trap for unwary novices who code `if (a = b + c)` when they mean `if (a == b + c)`. Both are valid, but generally the second one is what you meant, because the first assigns the value of `b + c` to `a` and then tests the truth value of `a`.

Because assignments are not expressions in Python but statements, you will get a syntax error for  `if (a = b + c)`. It's just as invalid as `if (return)`.

If you want to achieve what the C idiom does you can use an *assignment expression* (new in 3.8). You can explicitly code `if (a := b + c)` if what you really want to do is assign the value of `b + c` to `a` and then test the truth value of `a` (though technically I believe it actually tests the truth value of `b + c`; which comes to the same thing).

[And to the style martinets, yes, I *do* know that parens are redundant in a Python `if` statement.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this synthetic and clear answer. I am a python beginner and I usually program in C. So, I understand everything with your answer : _in C an assignment is an expression_ and _assignments are not expressions in Python but statements_. I read the PEP 572 and after, I think, I will have a new question.

Comment: I read something interesting in the PEP 572 _the = statement can be augmented to += and its friends, can be chained, and can assign to attributes and subscripts._ Nevertheless, the = statement can be augmented, can be chained but it is not possible to augment and chain this statement in the same line : `a *=10 -= 20` for example. Right ?

Comment: Right. Not possible. You get a syntax error.  You can chain `=` assignments, as in `a = b = c`, but it is not equivalent to `a = (b = c)` as it is in C, but rather to something like `a,b = (c,) * 2`.

Comment: Reading your comment, I tested (for fun) `(a,b)*=(10,100)` and it does not work. So, `=` could not be augmented in all situation.

Answer (score 1):

Doing them in one line would simply be

```
aaa = (aaa * 200) - 100
```

Though I doubt you'll see any performance difference between this version and what you wrote.

Comment: May I suppose that with this expression : 1) aaa is loop over one time for multiplication and a temporary array is created, 2) then this temporary array is loop over for substraction 3) then finally an affectation is done to the initial array aaa ?